error code C1083 (can not include xkeycheck.h no such directory) in VC++ Version 6.0
Iam getting this Error code c1083 in VC++ when try to build my project ,any help or suggestion is
highly appreciated.
I tried building the application but getting error during build , what more could i do to fix this
error

VC++ 6.0 was released on 1998. I would recommend porting/rebuilding that project with a modern/supported toolset from this millennium. That header is a part of the standard template library. I cannot recall if that actually shipped with VC++ 6.0. But the error indicates the file or directory its looking in doesn't exist.
